# SQL syntax for conditional select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select data from three tables. my logic should go like this:

Basically select from either one of the two tables which is determined by a column in table A.

```sql
Select a.orderid , 
if (a.ordertable= b) then b.order_info
else 
 c.order_info 
where 
a.order_id = b.order_id or a.order_id = c.order_id
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 5):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT a.orderid,
    CASE
        WHEN a.ordertable = b.? THEN b.order_info
        ELSE c.order_info
    END
FROM sparkles
WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id OR a.order_id = c.order_id
```

Comment: This query doesn't have a "from" clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff his doesn't either. But I will update. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind is two subqueries, union'ed together to get the results from each table:

```
select *
from ((select b.order_info
       from b join
            a
            on a.order_id = b.order_id and
               a.ordertable = 'b'
      )
      union all
      (select c.order_info
       from c join
            a
            on a.order_id = c.order_id and
               c.ordertable = 'c'
     )
    ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the row in table b or c may or may not exist, I think you need this:

```
select  a.orderid,
        case 
            when a.ordertable = 'b' then b.order_info
            else c.order_info
        end as order_info
from    a
left 
join    b
        on a.orderid = b.orderid
left 
join    c
        on a.orderid = c.orderid
```